# IIS (AWS) Deployment Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, amazon-web-services

I am having some problems deploying an app I created to IIS on Amazon AWS. I have basically taken a sabbatical from development and haven't deployed an app in over a year.

The app has been transferred across fine and runs to the point of causing errors and displaying that frameworks are missing etc. I solved this in the past by:

1. Changing what version of .NET was being used on the server
2. Including all DLLs when the programme actually transferred (not what it does by default)

For the life of me, I cannot remember how to include all DLLs when deploying the programme so those can be relied on instead of the system's frameworks. Can someone please remind me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do Right Click on Project and select **Add Deployable Dependencies** from the context menu

[image]

> As of MVC4, all necessary assemblies to run an MVC application are
>   automatically added to the bin directory, and any MVC4 application is
>   bin-deployable (means you can run it in a server without explicitly
>   installing MVC) . For this reason, the Include Deployable Assemblies
>   dialog has been removed from Visual Studio 2012

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441585/1241400

Comment: That is awesome about MVC4. Had no idea. Means I should try to push my company a little harder to make the switch from 3. ;]

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I was looking for. Definitely should make the switch to MVC 4 too then if thats the case

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance talking about [Bin Deploying MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx)? It's kind of a pain to do, considering you need to remember to make sure those dependencies are in your bin folder any time you either move the application around, put it on a new server, etc.

What errors is your displaying? I think you'd probably be better off resolving those, if possible. Windows has gotten much friendlier with installing updates in the past few years.