# Difference Between C# 7, .Net standard, PCL, .Net Core, and .Net 4.7

Tags: .net, .net-core, c#-7.0, .net-standard, .net-4.7

Can anyone explain how each of these differ? I'm beginning to get confused as to what the differences are and good use cases for when to each one.

The difference between my question and this question: [Difference between .Net Core, Portable, Standard, Compact, UWP, and PCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514546/difference-between-net-core-portable-standard-compact-uwp-and-pcl)  is that they do not speak of c# 7 and .net 4.7 and how they all relate to .net core, .net standard, and PCLs which is what I need to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C#` is a programming language, using which you can create a programs, with some [new features in 7th version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

[`.Net Standard`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) is a rule (well, standard) by which libraries should be built to be understandable by each other.

[Portable Class Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) is a special version of libraries being able to be consumed either by `.Net` Framework or `.Net` Core.

[.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/index) is a framework, like general .Net, with different architecture, which supports .Net Standard starting from `v1.6`, so it cannot easily interact with previous versions of `.Net`.

[`.Net 4.7`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/) is a new version of `.Net` Framework [which supports .Net Standard 1.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) too, so it would be able to interact with a `.Net` Core apps.

[Announced `.Net` Standard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md) will provide a universal platform for `.Net` Framework, `.Net` Core, Xamarin, etc., to run.

Comment: I am sorry I am still unsure and want your expertise here. Is .NET4.7.x same as .NET 7. I am looking to install SDK 7.0.x and ASP.NETCore runtime 7.0.x. I hope you won't disappoint me! Finally I found the installers here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0. I have downloaded the x64 installers for Windows OS but I am not able to run the setup after double clicking on the downloaded files. What could be wrong?

Comment: @SujitPrabhakaran No, 4.7 is a framework which is quite old, about 2017 year.. Net (Core) 7 is ongoing version from late 2022 year. You can't switch between them.