# Can I run my .NET program in a container?

Tags: rhel.net

I’m just starting out with containers and was wondering if I can run my .NET program in a container. What’s the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a Web application, you could use **.Net Core**, that runs on Windows and Linux (Desktop, VM, Docker).

Some useful links:

- [What is .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908049/what-is-net-core)
- [Official page - install guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)
- [Official .Net core docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/)

Comment: The application does not have to be a web application, you can also write a console application which has nothing to do with the web and run it in a container afaik

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can containerize .NET Framework apps and run them in windows containers: https://www.docker.com/products/windows-containers

I would recommend using .NET Core if your codebase isn't huge (either a small app or a greenfield project) and you don't need any .NET Framework/Windows specific libraries.