# Does goDaddy support asp.net 4.5 and asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, hosting, web-hosting, asp.net-4.5

i want to host my asp.net mvc-5 with asp.net 4.5 inside go-daddy so does go-daddy supports asp.net mvc-5 & asp.net 4.5 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run MVC 5 on any windows host as long as you make sure you provived the MVC .dll's required.

On godaddys Site. [Link](https://www.godaddy.com/help/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mcv5-applications-8999)

> When you publish your site using an MVC4 or MCV5 application, make
>   sure you have .NET include the MVC dlls; they're included by default,
>   so there's no action required on your end. You might also need to
>   upload assemblies you want to use to a bin specific to your project.
>
> For MVC5 applications using Entity Framework, you'll also need to
>   change your CAS priv to "Full."

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, but is the info inside this link valid ?  https://howshost.com/godaddy-asp-net-hosting/  specifically regarding that Godaddy does not allow full trust for asp.net which might affect asp.net features ?

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mcv5-applications-8999

Comment: https://besthostingsearch.net/tutorial/caution-asp-net-shared-web-hosting-trust-level/

Comment: ok then i need to use Plesk account type ,,, but is this sentence valid :- (("GoDaddy doesn’t support Full Trust, which makes up one of the main factors why we try to stop you going with GoDaddy ASP.NET web hosting. You shall know that the Full Trust is an important feature that allows ASP.NET websites to fully utilize the .NET framework libraries and APIs. ")) ... even when using Plesk ?

Comment: Most shared hosting does not support full trust. full trust would give you access to the server file system. Most hosting companies give medium trust.

Comment: but from the link i provided it mentioned that asp.net will not work unless i have full trust ,,, not sure if this is valid ? now i host my asp.net MVC-5 on a hosting provider named discountasp.net and did not face any problem. so not sure i did not face any problem because i have full trust or becuase i do not need to have a full trust ?

Comment: also on godaddy web site they mentioned "For MVC5 applications using Entity Framework, you'll also need to change your CAS priv to "Full." so seems i can chnage the CAS trust level  to be full ,, so i can have full trust with godaddy by this is not set by default ? is this correct or i am not understanding it correctly ?

Comment: We have 3 customers that run MVC applications on GoDaddy without issue.

Comment: You will need to look at this link as well. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Comment: thanks a lot for the links and help, i do not want to go into details now, but i wanted to check if Godaddy support asp.net mvc or not . now final question Godaddy mentioned "Only our Plesk Shared Hosting accounts support MVC4 and MCV5 applications. " , so now our customer mentioned that they already register a domain name and they already have emails register with godaddy,, but i am not sure if they have Pleask as their account type or not.. so from your knowledge can i chnage my go-daddy account type to be Pleask ? or this is something that need to be done when i register with godaddy?

Comment: You need to call customer support to see what hosting plan you have.

Comment: but are the hosting plans flexible to be changed ? so at the end regardless of what they have i can upgrade or downgrade to use Plesk ? did u get my point ?

Comment: They have two types of Windows hosting account, Plesk Control Panel & Web/Classic (Hosting Control Panel).  They  support MVC5 with their both the plans - Web/Classic (Hosting Control Panel) & Plesk Control Panel plans. The only thing is, you may need to tweak some settings. You can have detailed information about that here ... https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-aspnet-2531

Comment: @AccuWebHosting.Com so seems it is better to use Plesk for asp.net mvc5? is this correct ?

Comment: Thats true ... Go with Plesk.

Comment: @AccuWebHosting.Com thanks a lot.Now one last question, our customer already purchase a domain name along with an email from godaddy. so now i want to use this domain name to host the asp.net mvc-5 on it. But our customer is saying that thy cannot remember the customer# and the email address they used when they register the domain with go-daddy. so my question is; if our customer already purchase a domain name from godaddy , then this should mean that they should have a customer # ? and i need to login using this account info to deploy the new asp.net mvc-5 on the domain name? is this correct?

Comment: they need to call go-daddy for their info, you should have an account with go-daddy and then you can send a request for management access to their account from inside your account. that just makes life easy rather than having many accounts to document and control.

Comment: @RichBailo thanks for the reply... so you mean they can not purchase a domain name with godaddy unless they have an account this is correct ? i will call godaddy but i want to make sure they already have an account ? or godaddy allow purchasing a domain name without registering an account first ?

Comment: when they purchase a domain they are automatically creating an account with them.

Comment: @RichBailo now i will chose the "Plesk" as the plan ,, but can you adivce if i will get these 2 options inside the Plesk; 1) the ability to deploy my application directly from Visual studio using web deploy ? 2) will i get an FTP connection ?

Comment: Yes to both, And you can deploy to ftp from visual studio.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great help.. i am going to deploy on godaddy using Plesk ,,

Answer (score 1):

The type of web hosting account you need for MVC is call Plesk Shared Hosting

> Only our Plesk Shared Hosting accounts support MVC4 and MCV5
>   applications.

[DO YOUR HOSTING ACCOUNTS SUPPORT MVC4 AND MCV5 APPLICATIONS?](https://www.godaddy.com/help/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mcv5-applications-8999)

Comment: So generally speaking  godaddy DO support asp.net mvc5 + asp.net 4.5 ? second question is this link https://howshost.com/godaddy-asp-net-hosting/ valid they say that hosting asp.net with go-daddy is not recommended ?

Comment: Yes you can run MVC on any windows as long as you export all the required .dll's needed to run the site. look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441568/do-i-need-to-install-mvc-3-4-on-web-server-to-run-mvc-application

Comment: but is this sentence valid (("GoDaddy doesn’t support Full Trust, which makes up one of the main factors why we try to stop you going with GoDaddy ASP.NET web hosting. You shall know that the Full Trust is an important feature that allows ASP.NET websites to fully utilize the .NET framework libraries and APIs. ")) ...  even when using Plesk ?

Comment: We have 3 customers that run MVC applications on GoDaddy without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from Godaddy on ASP.Net using shared hosting because:

I got the following information online:

I asked the asp.net team directly and this was their response
We officially announced that partial trust is no longer a trust boundary for the purposes of application isolation last year (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981) and as such our recommendation to shared hosting providers is to not use it anymore. Moving forward, we will not be supporting partial trust for new framework features we develop for this reason. I know lots of people using shared hosting and since host providers won't ever give full trust to their shared hosting products I am guessing Microsoft made this decision so they can get more clients on Azure.

When I asked Godaddy to provide the full trust requiered. Godaddy said that testing on their server works and that these were not the problem but something on my solution.
I included  and used Full, Medium and Low

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

And I tried many other suggestions I researched but my application was allyays blocked for a police server. Anything worked. I got:

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.