# About ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application Deployment on IIS of Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have a question about Web application deployment of ASP.NET MVC 3 on IIS of Windows Server 2016.
In changing the server from Windows Server 2008 to 2016, I deployed the ASP.NET MVC 3 web application on IIS of Windows Server 2016, but there is a phenomenon that 500 server error occurs, so I can not check the application operation.

What I tried:

As shown in the site below, the DLLs of MVC 3 were included in the package using Visual Studio "Add Deployable Dependencies".

[Do I need to install MVC 3/4 on web server to run mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441568/do-i-need-to-install-mvc-3-4-on-web-server-to-run-mvc-application)

Result:

Although some errors have been resolved, eventually, at the time of execution, ASP.NET errors do not appear on the Web screen, resulting in a 500 error response,
There is no error in either the error log or the event log, so I do not know what is wrong.

It is becoming anxious that MVC 3 may not be supported already.
Should I migrate to MVC 5?

Advice please.

Comment: There's no use in guessing the cause of the 500 error. See duplicate to obtain the actual error.

Comment: I tried <configuration> setting in web.config. But the error log is not displayed yet.